# Consequences of using -s and -d arguments in iptables

Tags: linux, firewalls, iptables

We are studying iptables for a Computer Systems Security course. We are confused as to what happens when the `-s` and `-d` arguments are both used in the same rule, such as:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 10.7.53.2 -d 10.7.53.5 -j REJECT
```

We know how to block ports coming in and going out as well as ip addresses. However, we are unsure as to what the line above does.

At first we thought it blocks output from one ip address to another, but when we tested this theory we found the assumption was invalid.

Comment: Could you explain what mean *it was untrue*.

Comment: what we thought the line was meant to do was not right

Comment: This may be better suited for [su] or [sf].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand:

Switch `-d` and `-s` are associated by a `and` expression.

But.

As you're talking about a *firewall*, and  `iptables -A OUTPUT` mean `iptables -t filter -A OUTPUT`, this seem not to be right:

chains `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` concern packet from or to **the** host (firewall).

This coud be usefull if your firewall hold many different IP address and want to make condition based on wich IP is used.

Even if `10.7.53.2` is the only (local) IP of your firewall, `-s` switch is clearly useless.

For blocking a traversing connexion, you have to instruct `FORWARD` chain.

iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.7.53.2 -d 10.7.53.5 -j REJECT